# Multi module maven project : Failed to execute goal on project, Could not resolve dependencies for project, Could not find artifact

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jenkins

I made a spring mvc application for school and we need to deploy it on jenkins. It's a maven project with 3 modules, one for the front end of the app, one for the java classes and one for the REST API of the app.

When I do **mvn clean install** locally on my PC it works perfectly without any problems. But when I try to build the app with Jenkins with the same options, it manages to build 2 out of the 3 modules, failing at the View module. I've already tried deleting the .m2 file. The server I'm trying to deploy it on is a payara server running on linux.

Here are the 4 pom.xml file of my project:

For the whole project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>javaSpringMvcForum</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.ucll</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <modules>
        <module>javaSpringMvcForum-domain</module>
        <module>javaSpringMvcForum-mvc</module>
        <module>javaSpringMvcForum-restapi</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <payara.home>/opt/payara41</payara.home>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <derby.version>10.14.1.0</derby.version>
        <hibernate>6.0.7.Final</hibernate>
        <jpa.version>2.7.1</jpa.version>
        <validation>2.0.1.Final</validation>
        <maven.war.version>2.3</maven.war.version>
        <spring.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <javaee.version>7.0</javaee.version>
        <glassfish>3.0.1-b09</glassfish>
        <jackson>2.9.4</jackson>
        <jackson-datatype>2.7.5</jackson-datatype>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>${derby.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${validation}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>${glassfish}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-datatype}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>javaSpringMvcForum</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.war.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <glassfishDirectory>${payara.home}/glassfish</glassfishDirectory>
                    <user>admin</user>
                    <passwordFile>${payara.home}/glassfish/config/password.txt</passwordFile>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <terse>false</terse>
                    <echo>true</echo>
                    <domain>
                        <name>domain1</name>
                        <adminPort>4848</adminPort>
                        <httpPort>8080</httpPort>
                    </domain>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <artifact>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Java classes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>javaSpringMvcForum-domain</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <groupId>org.ucll</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>javaSpringMvcForum</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.ucll</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

</project>
```

Front end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>javaSpringMvcForum-mvc</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.ucll</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>javaSpringMvcForum</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.ucll</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <javaSpringMvcForum>1.0-SNAPSHOT</javaSpringMvcForum>
        <spring-security-taglibs.ver>5.0.4.RELEASE</spring-security-taglibs.ver>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>javaSpringMvcForum-domain</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.ucll</groupId>
            <version>${javaSpringMvcForum}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>javaSpringMvcForum-restapi</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.ucll</groupId>
            <version>${javaSpringMvcForum}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-taglibs.ver}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

REST API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>javaSpringMvcForum-restapi</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.ucll</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>javaSpringMvcForum</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.ucll</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <javaSpringMvcForum>1.0-SNAPSHOT</javaSpringMvcForum>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>javaSpringMvcForum-domain</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.ucll</groupId>
            <version>${javaSpringMvcForum}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here is also the Jenkins console output while building just in case it might help: https://pastebin.com/Q6vBTv42

I have no idea why this happens because it builds perfectly locally but not on Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `REST API`, you defined

```
<artifactId>javaSpringMvcForum-restapi</artifactId>
<groupId>org.ucll</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Since `javaSpringMvcForum-restapi` is a dependency of `javaSpringMvcForum-mvc`, it should not be war. Change `packaging` of `restapi` to `jar` and try again.

For the different behavior between jenkins and local, it is likely you have already installed a jar version of `restapi` in your local repository before.

Comment: But I just realized that it might not be what I want, because I need the rest api to be available via the web, so when I make requests to myapi.com/api/ it return a web page

Comment: So `restapi` should be a war too. In this case, you need to figure out what "type" of dependency between `javaSpringMvcForum-mvc` and `javaSpringMvcForum-restapi`. If mvc is just calling rest api endpoint, this is not a maven dependency.

Comment: Yes you're right, I just noticed that for some reason there are some java classes in my REST API modules when they were supposed to be in my javaSpringMvcForum-domain module... Now it builds without any problem. Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

As the error log says, Jenkins fails because it can't find the jar javaSpringMvcForum-restapi:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT.

With **mvn clean install** you install it on your local machine, in your .m2 folder. But did you also provide a repository that is accessible for your Jenkins installation? Assuming you did not upload that jar to an accessible repository like maven central, a remote Jenkins won't be able to find that jar.